# Accessing nested arrays in Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, jagged-arrays

I have a function that takes an array of arrays and two input values. The function needs to return an array containing all of this information; however, once the third level of arrays is accessed, it copies a value of "undefined", instead of the actual array that is there.

I have also tried passing in a copy of the array instead of the original reference, but the same issue occurs.

```
function relation(list, x, y){
    var x = [list, x, y];
    return x;
}
```

The attempt using the copy function:

```
function copy(list){
    var newList = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        if (Array.isArray(list[i])){
        newList[i] = list[i].slice();
    }
        else newList[i] = list[i];
    }
    return newList;
}

function relation(copy(list), x, y){
    var x = [list, x, y];
    return x;
}
```

Regardless of which version of relation() is used, calling the function

```
var x = [0, [0, [0, 1, 2] ] ];

var y = relation(x, 5, 10);
console.log(y);
```

should be

```
[ [ 0, [ 0, [0, 1, 2] ] ], 5, 10]
```

But actually returns

```
[ [ 0, [ 0, [Array] ] ], 5, 10]
```

Likewise, when trying to access elements in the innermost array:

```
console.log(y[0][0][0]);
```

the function returns undefined.

Is there an easy way to copy this innermost array?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `console.log(JSON.stringify(y))` and you will realize that everything works as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

For a shallow copy of an array use the spread operator: `...`

```
let copy = [...array]
```

BTW be mindful of how you assign your variables: `var` **x** `= [list,` **x**,`y];`

```js
var nested = [0, [0, [0, 1, 2] ] ];

function notMuchChanged(array, x, y){
  let outerArray = [];
  let copyArray = [...array];
  outerArray.push(copyArray);
  outerArray.push(x);
  outerArray.push(y);
  return outerArray;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(notMuchChanged(nested, 5, 10)));
```